# Implement any using foldl

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell, and I need to implement a function that works like `any`, but it needs to be implemented with `foldl`.  This is what I have now:

```
myAny :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
myAny = undefined
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? As it stands, you are just asking for someone to write this for you.

Comment: In fairness, for a newcomer often writing the types is a hard enough step that this question already includes "what has been tried so far". We don't know whether the type was provided as part of the assignment, or is part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`foldl` is usually applied like `foldl (\acc x -> <newAcc>) <startingValue> <list>`, where `<starting value>` is the initial value of `acc` so in your case `False` may be suitable, and `<newAcc>` is computed based on the evaluation of `x` (a list element) and `acc` (the current value of your accumulator). In the end the accumulator is returned. For calculating the new accumulator you want it to be `True` if the condition is met, and the old accumulator, if it is not met. Your function then could look something like this:

```
myAny predicate list = foldl (\acc x -> if predicate x then True else acc) False list
```

hope that helps... but don't just echo it, check out [learn you a Haskell for great good's chapter on this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions)

Comment: Maybe it helps to visualize the list in extension. So `foldl g z` is a function that takes something with the form `[x1, x2, ... , xn]` and produces `(((z \`g\` x1) \`g\` x2) ... \`g\` xn)`